# tcl give a wrong result suming float numbers

Tags: terminal, tcl

using tcl 8.6, when run:

```
% expr 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
```

the expected value is 0.3 but instead get this

```
0.30000000000000004
```

could someone tell me how to get the right answer?

Comment: You'd use [`format`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm) in tcl to get a desired precision.

Comment: Oh, and [always brace your expr-essions](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Brace+your+expr%2Dessions).

Comment: @Shawn, I can't see how to get the right answer with tcl in the post you suggest, the code looks like javascipt, maybe is.

Comment: It's _exactly_ that issue. Tcl uses normal double precision floats (for computation about floats) so that kind of calculation will be hit by that problem. You can `format %.15g` the number to paper over the issue. Note that Tcl 8.6 is extremely careful to not lose bits of significance when converting to a string, but in this case that's what you want to do. Another option is the [bigfloat](https://tools.ietf.org/doc/tcllib/html/bigfloat.html) package in tcllib.